# How can I get an user input like (1, 2, 4) - between parenthesis - in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and need to get an user input between brackets in order to make my code work. Something like (1, 4, 5) - it will always be only 3 int numbers.

I have already tried scanf("%d %d %d",&x, &y, &a) but it crashes when i use the parenthesis.

Comment: Post a [mcve]//

Comment: Giulia,  What in `scanf("%d %d %d",&x, &y, &a)` do you think reads the commas of `"1, 2, 4"`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Remember that `scanf` is *not* your only option when it comes to doing input.  You can probably get it to work for this particular problem, but there are lots of things it just can't do.  If you're planning on continuing in C, you'll eventually hit situations that `scanf` is totally unsuited for, so the sooner you start learning about alternatives, the better.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    while (scanf(" (%d ,%d ,%d ) ", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
        printf("%d,%d,%d\n", a, b, c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the space in the scanf specification permits arbitrary (0..n) blanks, tabs, newlines to surround the delimiters.
ps:  as the commenters noted, there is no reason to not include a simple usable program like the above in your question.   In addition to making life easier for people who want to help you, it comforts them to know what you have tried.

Comment: you don't need space *before `%d`s*

Comment: makes sense.   in 35 years of C, that might be the first program I wrote with scanf in it....

Comment: A trailing white space in `" (%d ,%d ,%d ) "` is weak code - block until non-white space entered.  Suggest  `" (%d ,%d ,%d )"`